# Knative deployed pod is not able to access via browser initially but after executing the curl command in k8s cluster i can able to access in browser

Tags: knative

I want to access the browser first time without executing the curl command, Note - The initial commands like export IP address and config-map commands execute successfully.

```
apiVersion: serving.knative.dev/v1alpha1 
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: helloworld-go # The name of the app
  namespace: default # The namespace the app will use
spec:
  runLatest:
    configuration:
      revisionTemplate:
        spec:
          container:
            image: gcr.io/knative-samples/helloworld-go 
            env:
              - name: TARGET 
                value: "Go Sample v1"
```

I am not getting any error. My expectation is my pod wants to get created automatically when I am requesting my URL using  my browser.

Comment: That is the idea of Knative. Your pod spins up when it is needed. When you type the url that's a request that reaches the pod.

Comment: Hi Rinor, Thanks for your reply. I understand the concept of knative, but my doubt is, I could not able to access my pods whenever i given the Ip:port_no in browser, but if i curl in k8s cluster and then knative pods getting created and then its working in browser also. 
I dont understand this strange here.

Comment: Give the browser some time. The first time when the request comes in (while there are no pods) the request will be cached and the activator will increase the number of pods (using the autoscaler). Readiness checks kick in to verify that the pod is ready to recieve traffic and after that the cached request will be forwarded. I think it takes about 10seconds

Comment: I waited some time in browser also watching the pod status as well. but pod is not getting created and got the connection timeout error in browser but if execute this below command in cli
 curl -H "Host: helloworld.default.example.com" http://${IP_ADDRESS} 
then pod is getting created immediately. Also i am able to see the desired output in cli, then its working in browser.
Please advice.

Comment: This sounds to me that you are not using the Ingress Gateway to reach the pod while using the web browser, but the Kubernetes Service directly. You need to use an extension to add the header in your browser too.

Comment: Yes, I am using the service, Earlier it was the cluster IP i have exposed the cluster IP to node port and i am accessing my pod using the cluster_ip:node_port.

Do i need to make any changes in my existing setup. Can you please guide me.

Note : I have executed the required steps mentioned in knative.dev before i am accessing it from browser.

Comment: Added it as the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

When using Knative it is recommended that all your requests are routed through the Ingress Gateway, as such you ensure to make use of the additional capabilities provided by Knative like autoscaling (if pods are scaled down to 0)

The Kubernetes Service underneath is used just as a mechanism for collecting all endpoints of the running pods. If there are no running pods it cannot scale up and will return a default response when no backends are present.

The problem that you are having is exactly this, using the Kubernetes Service there are no pods running. You need to use the Ingress gateway. To do so grab its IP by executing the command below:

```
kubectl get svc -n istio-system \
  -l app=istio-ingressgateway \
  -o jsonpath='{.items[0].status.loadBalancer.ingress[0].ip}'
```

And use this IP in your browser. The immediate problem that you will face is that the ingress gateway routes based on the header and you lack the header. For this reason, install a chrome extension that adds the header on the request (I use ModHeader).

After adding the header in your chrome extension (in your case "Host: helloworld.default.example.com") opening the IP you will reach your pod even if it is down.

Comment: Get the IP manually for the ingress gateway by executing: `kubectl get svc --namespace istio-system` but as you can see I am assuming that you are using Istio as a gateway. If you are using another try to get all services with --all-namespaces and look for a gateway.

Comment: service/helloworld                               ExternalName   <none>           istio-ingressgateway.istio-system.svc.cluster.local   <none>
                             197d
service/helloworld-8rgzv-deployment              NodePort       10.98.96.91      <none>                                                8080:30598/TCP,8012:30985/TCP,802
2:30264/TCP,9090:31609/TCP   22h
service/helloworld-8rgzv-service                 ClusterIP      10.100.230.168   <none>                                                80/TCP,9090/TCP

Comment: I am getting below error,
ubuntu@master-kube:~$ curl http://10.ZZ.YY.XX:30598/
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 10.211.203.56 port 30598: Connection refused

Comment: I am using VM in vmware ,

istio-ingressgateway     LoadBalancer   10.110.191.27    <pending>     80:30644/TCP,443:32371/TCP,31400:30673/TCP,15011:32751/TCP,8060:32135/TCP,853:31329/TCP,15030:30203/TCP,15031:30766/TCP   199d

istio-system         istio-ingressgateway                     LoadBalancer   10.110.191.27    <pending>                                             80:30644/TCP,443:32371/TCP,31400:30673/TCP,15011:32751/TCP,8060:32135/TCP,853:31329/TCP,15030:30203/TCP,15031:30766/TCP   199d

Please advice using which IP and port i should access.

Comment: what distribution of Kubernetes are you using?

Comment: Yes I am using istio-ingressgateway,
Kubectl get svc give o/p,
service/helloworld                               ExternalName   <none>           istio-ingressgateway.istio-system.svc.cluster.local   <none>
                             198d
service/helloworld-8rgzv-deployment              NodePort       10.98.96.91      <none>                                                8080:30598/TCP,8012:30985/TCP,802
2:30264/TCP,9090:31609/TCP   23h
service/helloworld-8rgzv-service                 ClusterIP      10.100.230.168   <none>                                                80/TCP,9090/TCP

Comment: Your Kubernetes distribution is not able to provide you with an external IP address, hence why it is is in pending status. You need to consult the docs on how to get an external IP, for whatever installation of Kubernetes you have (minikube I guess)

Comment: Below k8s version i am using,
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"13", GitVersion:"v1.13.1", GitCommit:"eec55b9ba98609a46fee712359c7b5b365bdd920", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-12-13T10:31:33Z", GoVersion:"go1.11.2", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

Comment: Yes i understand i wont get the external IP but i am able to access using cluster_ip:node_port
can i get my pod created when i am accessing the ip:port using my browser.

Comment: Give it a try with those then

Comment: one more question, so with out the external IP, the pod won't create automatically when i am accessing it through browser. isn't it ?

Comment: I added the extension.. Still not working ... Thanks for your support Rinor :)

Comment: are you by chance running chrome on a different computer from where you are executing curl the command? Like one being executed from the VM and the other on your PC?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.
I am using curl command and browser in my lab environment only both are in same network. Also curl command is not working when ever i am giving the ip:port_no in cli. but if i am executing the curl -H "Host: helloworld.default.example.com" http://${IP_ADDRESS} in cli its working.

Comment: This is exactly what is expected, I think the extension is not properly configured. Play around with the extension in your browser and keep using the IP Address ✌

Comment: I am unable to add modheader extension in my google chrome but i added the same in mozila browser, but no luck.
i dont understand why i am getting below error in cli when i am using the same ip and port no as same as in browser.
ubuntu@master-kube:~$ curl 10.xx.yy.zz:30750
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 10.xx.yy.zz port 30750: Connection refused
ubuntu@master-kube:~$
but curl -H "Host: helloworld.default.example.com" http://${IP_ADDRESS} in cli its working fine.

Comment: Because the routing is based on the Host header. As per the implementation of Istio.

This means that the IP and port gets u to the ingress gateway. Meanwhile the gateway uses the header to forward to the service.